# Exposing a DataGridView's Columns Property on the Designer in a composite UserControl

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Suppose I have a composite UserControl (called 'ListTable'), consisting of a label, two buttons and a DataGridView. The label is the title for the DataGridView, and the two buttons are Add Row and Delete Row, with basic, obvious functionality.

How do I expose the DataGridView's columns in the Designer, so that I can edit the DataGridView's columns through the UserControl in the exact same way I would if editing the DataGridView itself?

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

Various combinations of wrapping the DataGridView's Columns property in the ListTable via a property titled 'TableColumns' of the form 'List', with various attribute values, such as:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility (DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(TableColumnEditor),
        typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public List<DataGridViewColumn> TableColumns
    {
        get
        {
            List<DataGridViewColumn> columns = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(col);
            }

            return columns;
        }
        set
        {
            this.table.Columns.Clear();

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in value)
            {
                this.table.Columns.Add(col);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where TableColumnEditor is:

```
class TableColumnEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public TableColumnEditor(Type type) : base(type) { }

    public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        object result = base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
        ((ListTable)context.Instance).TableColumns = (List<DataGridViewColumn>)result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

None of this has seemed to work. Most of this is just prayful patchwork that I don't completely understand.

So, the classic dilemma: I do need to sit down and learn about these innards, but I don't have the (work)time to do an unfocused, leisurely tramp through MSDN's more esoteric WinForms articles. Is the code above salvageable? Is it in the right direction?

Comment: Surely It's is too late for OP to receive answer in this question but for future readers here you can find an answer: [Expose Columns property of a DataGridView in UserControl and make it editable via Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787383/expose-columns-property-of-a-datagridview-in-usercontrol-and-make-it-editable-vi)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

Put a BindingSource on the Form (`BindingSource1`).

Set your DataGridView's Datasource to Binding1.

Open the designer for the Form in question, and assuming you want to show the columns for the `MyObject` class, enter the following:

```
this.BindingSource1.Datasource = typeof(YourNamespace.MyObject);
```