# WinForms. How to find TableAdapter and Fill DataTable at Design-Time

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datatable, design-time, dataadapter

Data in standart DataGridView looks too empty

[image]

and it is unclear how data look in customized, filled grid

I'm going to extend grid to look more complex but the result it will be visible only at run-time, when it have data.

So I want to fill DataTable at design time to see how the result looks in the Grid.
So I need to perfrom code

this.MyDataTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.dBTestDataSet.MyDataTable)

I can get this.dBTestDataSet.MyDataTable from 
DataSource when DataSource is assigned by BindingSource using next code:

```
  if ((DataSource is BindingSource) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataMember))
  {
    BindingSource bindingSource = (DataSource as BindingSource);
    if ((bindingSource.DataSource is DataSet) && (bindingSource.DataMember is String))
    {
      DataSet dataSet = (bindingSource.DataSource as DataSet);
      DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[bindingSource.DataMember];
      return dataTable;
    }
  }
```

now I have MyDataTable

but how can I get MyDataTableTableAdapter?

I don't see any connection between MyDataTable and MyDataTableTableAdapter in the porject code

Although the development environment correctly shows the DataAdapter under every DataTable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you describe more about what's your goal exactly?

Comment: As I understood, there is access to TableProvider in design-time needed or another way to display real data from data table in grids in **design-time**.
IMHO, this is useful feature, and in Embarcadero RAD Studio (Delphi) something similar is relised: we can view live data from DataSet in any attached (binded) data controls.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not a good idea to load actual data to designer. You can fill `DataGridView` using some fake data, the same way which web forms designer do it for ASP.NET `GridView` control.

> **Q:** How can I get MyDataTableTableAdapter? I don't see any connection between MyDataTable and
>   MyDataTableTableAdapter in the porject code.

Each dataset has an `XSD` file which contains the definition of data set schema and also contains some annotations which will be used for generating `TableAdapter` classes, for example it contains some nodes like:

```
<TableAdapter BaseClass="System.ComponentModel.Component" 
 DataAccessorModifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" 
 DataAccessorName="CategoryTableAdapter" 
 GeneratorDataComponentClassName="CategoryTableAdapter" 
 Name="Category"
 UserDataComponentName="CategoryTableAdapter">
```

You can parse the file and extract the related `TableAdapter` for the `DataTable`. As you can see above xml is the point which `TableAdapter` and `DataTable` relates to each other.

You can get the xsd file using Visual Studio API methods. Also as a more simple workaround you can set its `BuildAction` to `Embedded Resource` and get it from the compiled assembly.

**Note**

Another option which may satisfy your requirement is putting your `DataGridView` control in `UserControl` and load data in constructor of `UserControl`, this way when you put an instance of your `UserControl` on a form, since the designer executes the constructor of your `UserControl` then the `DataGridView` will be filled with data.

Then if you want to expose `Columns` property of `DataGridView` you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787383/expose-columns-property-of-a-datagridview-in-usercontrol-and-make-it-editable-vi).

**Example - Just for learning purpose**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataSourceChanged(e);
        TryToPopulateControl();
    }
    protected override void OnDataMemberChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataMemberChanged(e);
        TryToPopulateControl();
    }
    private void TryToPopulateControl()
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
            return;
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.DataSource is BindingSource)
                {
                    var bs = (BindingSource)this.DataSource;
                    if (bs.DataSource is DataSet)
                    {
                        var ds = bs.DataSource;
                        var table = bs.DataMember;
                        if (ds == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(table))
                            return;
                        var name = ds.GetType().FullName + ".xsd";
                        string result = "";
                        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .GetManifestResourceStream(name))
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var document = XDocument.Parse(result);
                        var node = document.Descendants()
                            .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "TableAdapter")
                            .Where(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value == table).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (node != null)
                        {
                            var tableAdapterName = node.Attribute("UserDataComponentName").Value;
                            var adapterType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                .GetTypes().Where(x => x.Name == tableAdapterName).FirstOrDefault();
                            var adapter = Activator.CreateInstance(adapterType);
                            var fillMethod = adapterType.GetMethod("GetData");
                            var dataTable = fillMethod.Invoke(adapter, new object[] { }) as DataTable;
                            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                                ((DataSet)ds).Tables[table].Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Could not load data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see how I fill data-table at design-time using real data in [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sHTJNZ). I prefer to not include it in the answer because it's just for fun (and learning purpose) and I wrote it just for you to have an idea about how to parse the `XSD` file. In the example, I suposed for the `XDS` file, you have set `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. But in general I don't recommend using it in a real environment this way. The second option which I shared is better.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about this answer or the [linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787383/expose-columns-property-of-a-datagridview-in-usercontrol-and-make-it-editable-vi) or if you find them useful :)

Comment: It seems your new questions are related to the requirement which you had here.  Don't miss this post: [Expose Columns property of a DataGridView in UserControl and make it editable via Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787383/expose-columns-property-of-a-datagridview-in-usercontrol-and-make-it-editable-vi)

Comment: @DmitryB Pretty old question, but when you find some time, it would be great if you can verify the solution :)